# android: camera.rotateY() mysteriously skews carousel

Tags: android, camera, rotation

So, I implemented a carousel just like the [Android 3D Carousel](https://www.codeproject.com/Articles/146145/Android-D-Carousel).

Now, as long as my **getChildStaticTransformation(View child, Transformation transformation)** method looks like this:

```
@Override
protected boolean getChildStaticTransformation(View child, Transformation transformation) {

    transformation.clear();
    transformation.setTransformationType(Transformation.TYPE_MATRIX);

    // Center of the view
    float centerX = (float)getWidth()/2, centerY = (float)getHeight()/2;

    // Save camera
    mCamera.save();

    // Translate the item to it's coordinates
    final Matrix matrix = transformation.getMatrix();
    matrix.reset();
    mCamera.translate(((CarouselItem)child).getItemX(), ((CarouselItem)child).getItemY(), 
                        ((CarouselItem)child).getItemZ());


    // Align the item
    mCamera.getMatrix(matrix);

    matrix.preTranslate(-centerX, -centerY);
    matrix.postTranslate(centerX, centerY);

    float[] values = new float[9];
    matrix.getValues(values);

    // Restore camera
    mCamera.restore();

    Matrix mm = new Matrix();
    mm.setValues(values);
    ((CarouselItem)child).setCIMatrix(mm);

    //http://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=35178
    child.invalidate();
    return true;
}
```

everything looks fine:

[image]

but as soon as I add a y-rotation:

```
@Override
protected boolean getChildStaticTransformation(View child, Transformation transformation) {

    transformation.clear();
    transformation.setTransformationType(Transformation.TYPE_MATRIX);

    // Center of the view
    float centerX = (float)getWidth()/2, centerY = (float)getHeight()/2;

    // Save camera
    mCamera.save();

    // Translate the item to it's coordinates
    final Matrix matrix = transformation.getMatrix();
    matrix.reset();
    mCamera.translate(((CarouselItem)child).getItemX(), ((CarouselItem)child).getItemY(), 
                        ((CarouselItem)child).getItemZ());

// rotation start
    float rotationAngle = ((CarouselItem)child).getCurrentAngle();

    if(rotationAngle > 90){
        rotationAngle = 180 - rotationAngle;
    }
    if(rotationAngle < -90){
        rotationAngle = 180 - rotationAngle;
        rotationAngle = -1 * (360 - rotationAngle);
    }

    mCamera.rotateY(rotationAngle);
    // rotation end

    // Align the item
    mCamera.getMatrix(matrix);

    matrix.preTranslate(-centerX, -centerY);
    matrix.postTranslate(centerX, centerY);

    float[] values = new float[9];
    matrix.getValues(values);

    // Restore camera
    mCamera.restore();

    Matrix mm = new Matrix();
    mm.setValues(values);
    ((CarouselItem)child).setCIMatrix(mm);

    //http://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=35178
    child.invalidate();
    return true;
}
```

The position of the items is screwed up, look the relative distance of the items to the center item:

[image]

I'm out of ideas. Any idea where this comes from?

Answer (score 0):

You have to switch the direction of matricies' multiplication.
I mean, you have to apply rotation first. Only after that you can translate the object.

The direction of usage: Scale , Rotation, Translation.

Comment: So move the line
   **mCamera.translate(((CarouselItem)child).getItemX(), ((CarouselItem)child).getItemY(), 
                        ((CarouselItem)child).getItemZ());**
after **// rotation end** ?

Comment: moving the line mentioned above didn't do the trick. The carousel looks differently, but still weird. Did I switch the wrong lines?

Comment: If I have the line for rotation first, then the lline for translate, the carousels items are further apart and the items go up and down (from the center item: go up, down, stay, up and down).